# Integer solution to $x^4 + x^3 = y^4 +7$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, polynomials

> Find an integer solution or show there are none of $$x^4+x^3=y^4+7$$

I have found using python that there are no solutions for x, y less than 100

but also that the equation has at least one solution modulo n for every n less than 100 so I can't attack in the usual way by showing it has no solutions mod n for some n.

Could someone suggest an alternate method/ approach I could use?

(not looking for a straight solution just some hints or tips)

Comment: Well, $(x,y)=(-2, \pm 1)$ works (by inspection).

Comment: thanks. I completely ignored negatives =(

Answer (score 5):

Hint: $$x^4< x^4+x^3-7\leq (x+1)^4\iff x\geq 2$$

> If $x<0$ then $x=-t$ for $t>0$ and then $$x^4+x^3-7 = t^4-t^3-7$$

> Now for $t> 2$ we have $$(t-1)^4< t^4-t^3-7 < t^4$$

> So you have to check for $x\in\{-2,-1,0,1,2\}$

Comment: doesn't this only rule out $$x>=2$$ for $$x = y$$

Comment: Sorry, I don't follow you?

Comment: your argument seems to assume x=y but I may be missing something

Comment: The point is that if $x^4 + x^3 - 7$ is strictly between two consecutive $4$'th powers, it can't be a $4$'th power.